# Assuming that 5 cards are drawn with replacement, what is the chance that there are 3 cards of rank Ace and 2 cards of rank King?

Tags: probability

I have the answer, but there is one step that I don't understand.

So the total sample space is $52^5$, as 5 cards are drawn, one card is drawn each time from 52 cards. 
3 ace out of 4, that is $4^3$ and 2 king out of 4 thats $4^2$. But the final answer is $(5C3*4^3*4^2)/52^5$
Where does the $5C3$ comes from?

Comment: This counts the number of ways we can choose **where** the $3$ Aces occur.

Comment: why does it counts the Ace but not the King? Like why can't it be where the 2 Kings occur, then it would have been $5C2$?

Comment: That's OK, $\binom{5}{3}=\binom{5}{2}$. Once we have chosen where Aces go, there is only one way to choose where the Kings go, and vice-versa.

Comment: There is a notation called a multinomial coefficient, which for this example could be written $\binom{5}{3,2}$ to indicate that there are $5$ places and you want to fill $3$ of them with aces and $2$ of them with kings. When all the places are filled with just two kinds of things, this is equivalent to a binomial coefficient: $\binom{5}{3,2}=\frac{5!}{3!2!}=\binom53=\binom52.$ But if you had more than two kinds of things to count then a single multinomial can count the arrangements, whereas a single binomial cannot.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 ways in which cards can be drawn. Therefore multiply by 5!. And since 3 cards and 2 cards are of the same rank divide by 2! and 3!. Altogether they combine to form 5C3.